# Sort string based on user input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, user-input, letter

The question is how to sort the letter in alphabetic order based on the input in a HTML input tag, then clicks a button to sort it, after click the button the input will move to a text area and is already sorted when button is click, so that button need to have the insert function and sorting function, now the input can be insert to the textarea but not sorted, thanks.
Example of input:
andwe
output:
adenw

i want to define my input as an element, and write onclick="sortstring(element of my input)" in button, but i dont know how to define and dont have a sort function yet.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sortString() {
  const inputElement = document.getElementById('input');
  const sortResult = inputElement.value.split('').sort().join('');
  inputElement.value = sortResult;
  
}
```

```html
<input id='input' type="text" value=''/>
<button onclick="sortString()">sort</button>
```

Comment: The question asked how to do this with user input and a button that they click on. None of that is in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sortString(str) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = str.split('').sort().join('')
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup='sortString(this.value)'>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Please put the sample code in a stack snippet so it can be executed.